# Why all function in <cstring> must not have constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++17

I just noticed that [D0202R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0202r1.html) propose that all `<cstring>` functions **must not** have `constexpr`. I would like to understand why, during Jacksonville meeting, it was decided for a solution like this.

Take a function like `std::strchr`. I really do not see any reason for not being constexpr. Indeed, a compiler can easily optimize some [dummy code like this](https://godbolt.org/g/LtwukU) at compile-time (even if I remove builtins, as you can see from the parameters). However, at the same time, it is not possible to rely on these functions within constexpr contexts or using static assertions.

We could obviously re-implement some of `<cstring>` functions to be constexpr (as I did in [this other dummy code](https://godbolt.org/g/6EnWpa)), but I do not understand why they must not have `constexpr` in the standard library.

What am I missing?

---

#### PS: Builtins!

At the beginning I was confused because constexpr functions using some `<cstring>` capabilities *just worked*, then I understood it was only thanks to GCC builtins. Indeed, if you add the `-fno-builtin` parameter, you can just use `std::strlen` instead of the custom version of the function.

Comment: Changing signatures and implementations, relative to the C headers, is more work to implement than just the added signatures that C++ currently requires. Anyway you have a `constexpr` find function in `std::char_traits`. Or will have, in C++17. :)

Comment: I'm guessing because `<cstring>` is often a wrapper around a straight `#include` of a polyglot (C and C++) `string.h` file, so adding C++-specific keywords to `string.h` would break any C consumers, and wrapping it in `#ifdefs` or adding `#define constexpr  ` would be too cumbersome and potentially have unintended consequences.

Comment: Whenever you mess with something from the C library (which often comes from the OS, independent of the C++ standard library implementation), things get messy. Look at [the tricks needed to get `<cmath>` and `<math.h>` to work as specified](https://developerblog.redhat.com/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I found this _constexpr weakness_ just because neither gcc or clang are implementing a constexpr _std::(experimental::)string_view::find_ and I was trying to make some tests ;)

Comment: @Dai Actually, this is not exactly true. Indeed, <cstring> wraps around C functions, also including them in the _std::_ namespace and making some #undef-s (see the link given by @T.C.). However, if the C++ standard would explicitly say that, for instance, _std::strchr_ is constexpr, <cstring> could declare something [like this](https://godbolt.org/g/HhR0QP)

Comment: Can you give an example where this would actually be useful and couldn't be handled with `sizeof`?

Comment: @Omnifarious the second example is straightforward and cannot be handled with sizeof. But IMHO the _usefulness_ is not a matter of discussion in this case, otherwise we would not have std::string_view constexpr methods. From a practical point of view, my question is meaningless because everything related to constexpr strings can be handled with std::string_view in C++17. Indeed, my question is mainly related to the reasons behind the _cstring constexpr_ rejection during Jacksonville.

Answer (score 3):

Upon reviewing this more, and thinking more about the implications of the C++14 relaxation of rules surrounding `constexpr`, I have a different answer.

The `<cstring>` header is a wrapper around a bunch of C functions. C has no `constexpr` concept, and while it might be useful for it to have one, it's not likely to grow one anytime soon. So marking up those functions in that way would be cumbersome and require a lot of `#ifdef`s.

Also (and I think this is the most important reason) when those functions are not compiler intrinsics they are implemented in C and stored in a library file as object code. Object code in a library is not a form accessible to the C++ compiler to evaluate at compile time. They are not 'inline' like template code is.

Lastly, most of the really useful things they do can easily be implemented in terms of the C++ `<algorithm>` library. `strlen(s)` = `(::std::string_view(s)).length()`, `memcpy(a, b, len)` = `::std::copy(b, b + len, a)` and so on. And [D0202R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0202r1.html) proposes to make those algorithms `constexpr`. And, as you pointed out, it also proposes to make functions in `::std::string_view` `constexpr` and these also give equivalent functionality. So, given the previously mentioned headaches, it seems that implementing `constexpr` for the `<cstring>` functions would be of dubious benefit.

As a side note, there's `::std::copy`, `::std::move`, `::std::copy_backward`, and `::std::move_backward` and it's up to you to figure out which you need to call. It would be nice if there was a function that could figure out whether or not `x` or `x_backward` was needed in that particular case like `memmove` does. But, because of the way iterators are defined, taking one iterator and comparing it to another iterator that may not be iterating over the same object at all just isn't possible to do in C++, even if they're random access iterators.

Comment: `<algorithm>`s are not `constexpr`.

Comment: @yurikilochek - In the context of the question (asking about D0202R2) they are. That proposal is specifically about making them `constexpr`.

Comment: Right, my bad, did not bother to follow the link. Still `::std::find(s, s + largevalue, '\0') - s` is UB when `s + largevalue` is beyond the end of the buffer containing the string. Which basically means you have to know buffer size to use it.

Comment: @yurikilochek - That's true. Though `strlen` has a similar problem. :-)

Comment: @yurikilochek - And neither does `::std::find`. But if there is no `'\0'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138565/discussion-between-yuri-kilochek-and-omnifarious).